# Process.getInputStream() doesnt return all lines

Tags: java, linux, process, inputstream, processbuilder

My code looks like this:

```
public List<String> linux(String... commands) throws Exception{

    Process p = null;
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    p = builder.start();

    BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    String line;
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) lines.add(line);

    return lines;
}
```

But it didn't return all the outputs. I tried in the actual remote machine, there were about 100+ lines, but I only got 30 lines. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Chances are that the process you're trying to capture its output writes the missing lines to its error stream (consider reading `p.errorStream()` as well)

Comment: And/or that you need to close the process's input stream so it isn't waiting for anything from you.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have shown us *will* read all lines written by the process to its standard output.  The `readLine()` call will only return a `null` when it has reached the end-of-stream for the pipe that it is reading from; i.e. after all reading all lines.

The `readLine()` call can only **see** the end-of-stream if the other end of the pipe (i.e. the external process) has closed it.  You cannot get `null` by reading "too quickly".  And conversely, if `readLine()` does return `null` for a given stream, any / all subsequent calls will return `null`.  There is no point in retrying the readLine() if it returned `null`.

Also, you shouldn't use `isAlive()` to decide when to stop reading  ... as suggested by someone else.  The availability of unread output, and process termination are orthogonal issues.

Given that your code for reading the output is correct (I think so), there are just two possible explanations for the missing output:

1. Some of the process output was written to the processes standard error stream rather than its standard output.

   Solution: You can get the contents of the standard error stream by reading from the stream returned by getErrorStream().  But a simpler alternative is to get `ProcessBuilder` to *redirect* the standard error output to standard output.
2. The external process terminated without flushing its output buffers.  That could mean that some lines were never actually output by the process.

   Solution: You need to fix the external application.  This cannot be remedied from the Java application side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you've made my day! I was struggling with the execution of "hping3" command in Linux, and it turns out that part of the input goes into the error stream... Can you explain what's the point of doing that? If there are no errors, why put part of the input into the error stream? Thanks!

Comment: @PabloInsua - You would need to talk to the authors of the software to find out why they did it.  Or look at the source code for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like the Charset is not UTF-8 if it errors as soon as 'é' occurs. It's probably Extended ASCII, but if that doesn't work I'd try to figure out what Charset it really is.

It would fail on the entire line because of the BufferedReader.

Comment: If there was some problem with encodings, it would either map the characters to something else or throw an exception.  It wouldn't cause lines to disappear, or `null` to be returned prematurely.

Comment: sure, in case this person hasn't solved the problem in the last five and a half years

Comment: The point is the hundreds of *other* people who have read this, and continue to read this, and who may waste their time trying to solve their problem the wrong way.